# Tabla dinamica html

Tags: javascript, java, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table  class="table table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Codigo</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Unidad</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Valor unitario</th>
        <th>Valor total</th>        
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabProd" name="ProdLista" >
    </tbody >
</table>
```

y tengo la siguiente función con la cual la relleno:

```
function añadirFila(){
             if (document.getElementById("prod_cod").value!=="" &&
                    document.getElementById("cant").value!=="" &&
                    document.getElementById("prod_nom").value!=="" &&
                    document.getElementById("precUni").value!=="") {
                var table = document.getElementById("tabProd");
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                var celda1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var celda2 = row.insertCell(1);      

        celda1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("prod_cod").value;
        celda2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("prod_nom").value; 
           $.ajax({
           url:'SrvBuscaProductoUnidad',
           data:{codProdBusca:document.getElementById("prod_cod").value},
                type:'POST',
                dataType:'json',
                success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                    if (data.length>0) {
                        var filasJson=data.length;
                        var objeto=eval(data);
                        var selectUnidades;
                        for(var i=0;i<filasJson;i++){
                        selectUnidades+="<option  value="+objeto[i].uni_nombre+">"+objeto[i].uni_nombre+"</option>";
                        }
                        $("<td />").html('<select onchange=\"datoCelda()\" class="form-control" ">'+selectUnidades+'</select>').appendTo(row);
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#resConsultaCodigo').append("Busqueda sin resultados");
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error al consultar en la base de datos:'+textStatus);
                }
                });

                var celda3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var celda4 = row.insertCell(3);
                var celda5 = row.insertCell(4);
                celda3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("cant").value;
                celda4.innerHTML = document.getElementById("precUni").value;

                var valunit=document.getElementById("precUni").value*document.getElementById("cant").value;
                valorTotal=valorTotal+valunit;
                var valunitdecimal=valunit.toFixed(2);
                celda5.innerHTML = valunitdecimal;



                var celdaProducto=document.createElement('input');
                var celdaProductoNombre=document.createElement('input');
                var celdaCantidad=document.createElement('input');
                var celdaPrecUnitario=document.createElement('input');                    
        }
        else{
            alert('Ingrese los campos de Cantidad, precio y producto');
        }
}
```

Mediante la llamada de `ajax` en la función anterior relleno el `select` de cada producto, pero tengo el problema de que no  puedo cambiar el valor del precio al cambiar la unidad dentro del `select` de la fila porque como son varias filas dentro de la tabla, no se como manipularlos

Es recomendable hacerlo de esta manera o existe algún framework que me permita cambiar los valores dependiendo del item escogido en el `select` y que ademas me permite realizar acciones tales como cambiar la cantidad dentro de cada fila y/o eliminar las filas?

Comment: por la forma en que haces la llamada asincrona, ya estás usando un framework: jquery. ¿me equivoco?

Comment: pues si lo estoy usando pero a lo que me refiero es a poder manipular todos los eventos como se da en .net, soy nuevo en desarrollo web y me esta costando mucho trabajo el manejo de tablas